# display a redmine wiki in another redmine wiki page

Tags: redmine, wiki

Is there a way to display the content of a redmine wiki page in another page ?

I wish to write a unique page and display its content in different articles, instead of writing the article twice or just putting a link to the other wiki page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's already supported,

From http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineTextFormatting,

```
include

    Include a wiki page. Example:

    !{{include(Foo)}}

    or to include a page of a specific project wiki:

    !{{include(projectname:Foo)}}
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't think it could have been in the "macro" section...which was pretty much where I stopped reading the documentation :S

Answer (score 0):

In my case following code works:

```
{{include(Foo_article_name)}}
```

(without !exclamation mark at the begin).